# Updating multiple columns using case conditional clause

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

In the following `TSQL` code the second column `TypeId2` is not updated. 
What could be the problem here?

```
declare @dd table(Id int,number int, TypeId int)
declare @tt table(Id int,TypeId1 int, TypeId2 int)
insert into @dd values(25,10, 1),(25,15, 2)
insert into @tt values(25,0,0)

update t set 
t.TypeId1=case when TypeId=1 then number end,
t.TypeId2=case when TypeId=2 then number end
from @tt t inner join @dd d on d.Id=t.Id

select * from @tt;
```

After executing the above code and selecting data from `@tt` I get the following result:

```
Id  TypeId1 TypeId2
-------------------
25    10      NULL
```

which is not acceptable because the value of `TypeId2` is null, it should be 15.

Comment: The record in UPDATE may be updated only once. So it is updated using random (in your case - first) source record, and possible update using another record is ignored. You must combine source, then update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check:

```sql
UPDATE @tt
SET @tt.TypeId1 = t.TypeId1, @tt.TypeId2 = t.TypeId2
FROM @tt
JOIN ( SELECT Id, 
              MAX(CASE WHEN TypeId=1 THEN number END) TypeId1,
              MAX(CASE WHEN TypeId=2 THEN number END) TypeId2
       FROM @dd
       GROUP BY Id ) t
ON @tt.Id = t.Id
```

Comment: It works thanks, but what is the reason my method is not working?

Comment: @AsrarAhmadEhsan I had explained this in a comment to your question.